# vich_uploader.download_handler / StreamedResponse get file instead of response

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I try get file from FTP filesystem

```
 $this->container->get('vich_uploader.download_handler')->downloadObject($file,'file');
```

this return StreamedResponse

How i can get file instead of stream, there exist method  in vich_uploader get file ?

(I must download file from ftp storage and create new file localy so need binary and put it as new file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it is easy from gaufrette

```
  $filesystem = $this->container->get('gaufrette.product_uploads_ftp_fs_filesystem');

$filesystem->read($file->getOriginalName())
```